# Communication between two domain or subdomain without url rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, laravel-5.1

I have two servers. For instance let's call them SERVER-A with domain name www.server-a.com, and SERVER-B with domain name www.server-b.com. My codebases are written in magento and laravel.

Now my requirement is that when i access www.server-a.com/example it actually renders the page from www.server-b.com/example without rewriting the url.

Redirection was a good option, but as i cant hamper the current url as a lot of seo is related to it, so i want to create an alternate option.

I checked out a lot of option for this kind of a communication but all the options found somehow seem incomplete from some or the other perspective.
Options checked are:

1. Load the external page via IFRAME.
2. Use php fopen(www.server-b.com).
3. CORS communication using jsonp or document.domain.
4. The idea to implement a 3rd layer between the two servers with lets them communicate internally through itself(with the help of node.js etc ->still trying to figure out where i can go with this.) 
   etc

But none of them gives me the resolution i need. Is their really a way where i simply type www.server-a.com/example in the url and the page which loads is actually from www.server-b.com/example without rewriting the url or letting the user know that he has left the original site he has landed on to.

NOTE:- I am the owner of both the servers in this case. Also the separate domains can be changed into subdomains as per requirement. pls feel free to make any tweaks to the base configuration to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod proxy

On server A apache config

```
ProxyPass /example http://www.server-b.com/example
ProxyPassReverse /example http://www.server-a.com/example
```

First line: Every request on server-a/example will be redirect to http://www.server-b.com/example
Second line: When server-b answer the request, the url show will be http://www.server-a.com/example

Don't forget that you will need mod_proxy installed and enabled on apache.

Comment: Thanks Joao. I did look on to this method as well. But Was not sure if it will rewrite the url. So u have made it clear now. Now the issue is i have nginx. So need to see if mod_proxy is allowed between nginx and apache. Anyways thanks a lot for the reply.